# compileOnSave does not work in VS 2015 after upgrading to TS 2.0

Tags: typescript

I have compileOnSave turned on in tsconfig.json.  This setting used to work in TS 1.8.  I just re-opened the project, and the setting no longer works.  I still use workaround from here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8518 .  The installer for TS 2.0 did not overwrite the file though.  Should it?  Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the workaounrd was causing issues.  I manually updated the services file from here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/release-2.0/lib/typescriptServices.js and the issue was solved.